# HTML5 Camera input tag not allowing existing image selection

Tags: html, camera

I'm using the HTML5 capture image input tag. Here is my input tag:

```
<input id="imagesInput" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" class="input-file" multiple>
```

However, when I click this input I am taken to the camera. I am not given the "choose existing file" like I was before.

I have tested this on both an Ipad and an Android phone with the same result.

Does anyone know if I am missing an attribute or anything? Thanks!

Here is a simple jsfiddle to replicate the issue. You will only see this issue on mobile devices:
https://jsfiddle.net/u07o1ywx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. the capture="camera" attribute allows only the camera to upload. by adding this into the accept attribute, you can load from either.

```
<input id="imagesInput" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" class="input-file" multiple>
```

Comment: Actually, per the latest spec, you should just leave out the `capture="camera"` part and just use `<input id="imagesInput" type="file" accept="image/*" class="input-file" multiple>` . See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) for details. `accept="image/*;capture=camera"` is from a very old version of the spec.